# Where are pin1.0 and pin1.1 on MSP-EXP430F5529LP launchpad for MSP430?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, msp430, texas-instruments

I am looking at the pin-out here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slau536/slau536.pdf and can't find p1.0 and p1.1. Where are they?

The reason (perhaps, stupid) why I started looking for these two pins is because I need to connect RX and TX of a UART somewhere on the launchpad, and p3.3 and p3.4 did not work, and on some loosely related pinouts of other boards such as this: http://energia.nu/Tutorial_DigitalReadSerial.html p1.1 is RXD and p1.2 is TXD (not sure what's the difference between RX and RXD, assuming for now they are the same). So I thought maybe I try these pins and try my luck there? And now I can't find them.

BTW, the pinout shows that p3.3 and p3.4 are UART RX and TX on BoosterPack standard, which I don't have, and on the launchpad these pins are UCA0RXD and UCA0TXT (also, they are apparently UCA0SOMI and UCA0SIMO). I don't know yet what these abbreviations mean, and also, why there are two sets of functions on the same pins and how to switch between them.

My launchpad (in subj) documentation says it supports up to 4 hardware UARTs. Where? And why then is there a UART on booster pack?

Maybe p1.1 and p1.2 are taken for the launchpad's onboard backchannel UART?

Comment: Are there any pin select registers?

Comment: This is not an apprpriate question for stackoverflow, but why are you referencing teh marketing material rather than the [technical documentation and schematics](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430f5529lp?DCMP=msp-f5529&HQS=msp-f5529-b/)!? P1.1 is connected to S2 (switch) and P1.0 to LED1.  With respect to pin function multiplexing, read the [user guide for the part](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430f5529)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware/electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know where every pin goes on this board then you should look at the schematic in the [User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau533a/slau533a.pdf).  But more importantly, you should get familiar with the [datasheet for the microcontroller](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f5529.pdf) on the board.

You don't see P1.0 and P1.1 because those pins are not brought out to the booster pack headers (connectors).  Those pins are used within the launchpad board for something else.  (They are not even UART pins as you hoped.)

P3.3 and P3.4 is the only UART connection that you have available through the booster pack headers.  The other UART is on P4.4 and P4.5 and those pins aren't brought out through the headers.  So you should probably try to get P3.3 and P3.4 working.  Did you download TI's example software for this launchpad?  There is probably an example program that uses the UART.

P3.3 and P3.4 are multiplexed as are many GPIO pins on typical microcontrollers.  These particular pins can be configured as GPIO, a UART, or an SPI port.  SOMI and SIMO are abbreviations related to the SPI function.  Your code will have to configure these pins for the UART function.  Read the datasheet and study the example software to learn how to do this.

I'm not sure where you saw four UARTs.  The microcontroller on this particular launchpad has four serial interfaces but only two of those interfaces are designed for UARTs.  The other two serial interfaces can be SPI or I2C.